# Having two microphones on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: audio

is it possible to have two microphones on a Raspberry Pi? If it is, what are the solutions?

Answer (score 4):

Two cheap USB microphones should work. Or two USB sound cards with microphones plugged into them.

Comment: But what if all USB ports are in use already?

Comment: @Mohsen In that case a USB hub could be used. If the Pi can't supply it a powered hub can be used.